# Как сделать верстку

Tags: html, css

Вот такого примера?
http://prntscr.com/b4fna5
Я разрезала макет на картинки: Иисуса со звездой, логотип, храм, голубя, ветку
Подскажите, пож-ста.

```css
header{
    width:100%;
 height:400px;
}
#pict_ix{
 height:798px;
 background:url('images/ix.png') no-repeat;
}
#logo{
 position:relative;
 top:45px;
 left:250px;
 background:url('images/logo.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="swap">
    <header>
       <div id="pict_ix">
       </div>
       <div id="logo">   
       </div>
       <div id="church">    
       </div>
       <div id="bird">
       </div>
       <div id="tree">
       </div>
    </header>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Вырезать чувака со странной жёлтой шапкой, какую-то постройку справа и голубя. Фон (без надписи) поставить как `background`, вырезанные картинки позиционировать как удобнее, а надпись можно в `div` вставить и стилями оформить (хотя можно тоже как картинку, но это плохая практика).

Comment: @Other, то есть вы предлагаете в `html` делать `div` вместо `img`, а в `css` задать `background:url('путь к картинке')`? Тогда в `html` будут пустые дивы... Позиционировать это как?

Comment: @NNN просьба уточнить:
1. Данный блок идет на всю ширину сайта?
2. Сайт должен подстраиваться под ширину экрана пользователя (т.е. адаптивная верстка) или сайт с жестко заданной шириной?

Comment: @NNN 3. какой используется шрифт? если он является коммерческим, то стоит подумать о том, что проще было бы сохранить весь блок как картинку или отдельно текст как картинку (что является не очень хорошой практикой, но в данной ситуации вполне допустимо)

Comment: @Olegatro, Спасибо за понимание... Вот что я попыталась сделать. Да, у меня слабое понимание абсолютного и релативного позиционирования. Может,лит-ра есть и примерчики? Так делают верстку? 1. Данный блок на всю ширину.2 я делаю фиксироваанную верстку, до адаптивного мне далеко. 3. Шрифт Segoe Script. Мне бы хотелось проверить кроуссбраузерность.  Знаете как? Его надо доп устанавливать, но я пока не стала.

Comment: @NNN Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39830/discussion-beetwean-olegatro-and-nnn)

Comment: вообще вы если в фотошопе нарезали то там после нарезания (инструмент "раскройка") то потом доступно сохранить для web в котором указать просто и изображения и html , в этом случае ваше изображение превратится в вёрстку автоматически

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам можно сделать header{ position: relative;}, у элеменов #pict_ix, #logo {position: absolute;}. Дело в том что для них header - это родительный элемент. И Если у родителя значение position задано как fixed, relative или absolute, то отсчет координат ведется от края родительского элемента. Далее вы можете уже у каждого элемента картинки через свойства top, bottom, left, right задават координаты относительно Header.

В будущем если решите делать адаптивную верстку под разные экраны, вы легко сможете через @media поменять координаты каждого элемента или например при ширине экрана меньше чем ... px вообще отключить весь блок header и заменить его другим.